# The .NET Garbage collector

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

This is a very basic question. I am debugging some memory leaks and got totally confused. Suppose I have the following:

```
public class ObjectData : IDataObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectRepository<T> where T : IDataObject
{
    private Dictionary<int, T> Objects;

    public ObjectRepository()
    {
        Objects = new Dictionary<int, T>();
        // load Data
    }

    public T GetDataObject(int id);
    {
        return Objects[id];
    }

    public Reset()
    {
        Objects = new Dictionary<int, T>();;
    }
}
```

Now suppose I have the following program flow:

```
public Main()
{
    var DataRepository = new ObjectRepository<ObjectData>();

    // Constructor called and Data loaded

    var myObject = DataRepository.GetDataObject(1);

    DataRepository.Reset();

    // Call manually the garbage collector or leave it

    // Program flow continue after this
}
```

The question is, will the garbage collector get rid of the collection initially created by the constructor? Or it will not because one of the elements is still referenced in the program flow (`myObject`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be collected (eventually), since there is no more references to it. Getting a reference to something in a dictionary doesn't give you any reference to the dictionary itself! Unless that object somehow references the dictionary internally, that is.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! about the internal reference :)

Answer (score 1):

After your call to `Reset`, there is no strong references to your initial `dictionary`. Thus, it will be elected for garbage collection.

> Or it will not because one of the elements is still referenced in the program flow (myObject)?

It doesn't matter which objects the dictionary refers to, what matters is who refers to the dictionary. In this case, no one. It's perfectly possible for the dictionary to be collected while its contents are still alive.

Answer (score 1):

To answer such questions ask yourself: Who is referencing the object in question (in this case the overwritten dictionary)?

`DataRepository` is not. You overwrote the object reference pointing to the old dictionary.

`myObject` is not because `ObjectData` does not have any field of type dictionary. It can't reference a dictionary.

Nobody is left to reference the old dictionary.